# Java Tree Debugging

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a method to count all nodes of a tree from the root down. Basically I count the root then add the length of each of the roots child lists.

```
       public int size() 
       {
            int count = 1; //count the root node
            for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildren().size(); i++){
                count += (root.getChildren().get(i)).length() + 1;
            }
            return count;
        }
```

This is the solved solution.

Comment: Did you mean `count +=` instead of `count =`?

Comment: Don't delete/Remove your question text when you figure out the answer. If you want to dissassociate the question from yourself, flag it for a moderator. If you want to say it's been fixed, then answer the question and mark it as accepted or mark the answer that solved the problem for you. Your questions aren't just for you, they're for everyone that searches for a similar problem.

Comment: I changed the name in your account settings.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the `size()` method as a member of `ArrayTreeNode`. Use recursion. The size for a node is 1 plus the sum of the children's node sizes.

So inside your `size()` method you have two cases:

1. If the node is a leaf, return 1. Here is no recursive call.
2. If the node has children, call the size() method of all the children, calculate the sum, add 1 for the node and return that value.

Btw. why do you have both `tree` and `root` attributes in class `ArrayTree`? Isn't a root node enough? Why do you have a separate class `ArrayTree` at all? An `ArrayTreeNode` for itself is already a tree.

Where do you set the  `parent` attribute of your `ArrayTreeNode` class? Wouldn't it be best if you set the parent inside the `addChild()` method to ensure that `parent` is always valid?

**Update:**

Ok, you asked for an example. I think if you are not used to recursion it's not so easy to get your head around it.

This is a method of class `ArrayTreeNode`:

```
public int size() {
  int sum = 1; // Count at least this node

  // Ask every child for its size. If this node is a leaf,
  // then no recursive call happens.
  // Otherwise call the size() method recursively for ervery 
  // child node. The child's size() method may also call its 
  // own childs size() method, adding another level of recursion.
  // But we can be sure that the recursion comes to an end because 
  // at every leaf the simple answer will be 1. 
  for(ArrayTreeNode<E> child: children) {
    sum += child.size();
  }

  // return our calculated size. 
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a small example. I hope this clarifies the idea.